# Using graphql, I need to crate a mutation which includes an empty array

Tags: graphql

Below, I'm attempting to create a type Customer which will include and array of type Box.

In my addCustomer mutation, I need to create an empty boxes array which will later have Boxes pushed into to it.  I'm getting this error:

Error: The type of Mutation.addCustomer(boxes:) must be Input Type but got: [Box].

Any ideas?

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Customer {
    _id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    password: String
    address: String
    city: String
    state: String
    zip: String
    phone: String
    boxes: [Box]
  }

  type Auth {
    token: ID!
    customer: Customer
  }

  type Box {
    _id: ID!
    boxSize: String!
    sendToCustomer: Boolean!
    getFromCustomer: Boolean!
  }

  type Mutation {
    addCustomer(
      firstName: String!, 
      lastName: String!, 
      email: String!, 
      password: String!, 
      address: String!, 
      city: String!, 
      state: String!, 
      zip: String!, 
      phone: String!
      boxes: [Box]
    ): Auth
   
    login(email: String!, password: String!): Auth

    createBox(
      boxSize: String!,
      sendToCustomer: Boolean!,
      getFromCustomer: Boolean!
    ): Box

    addBoxToCustomer(
      customerId: ID!,
      boxSize: String!,
      sendToCustomer: Boolean!,
      getFromCustomer: Boolean!
    ): Customer
  }
```

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GraphQL Input Object Types and Object Types are not compatible. This means that you can't use an output object type as an input object type, even if they have the same structure.

For customer you have circumvented the problem by defining every field as an argument to the mutation. First, I would create an Box input type. I like to call these input types drafts and postfix them with `Draft` but many people in the community postfix with `Input`.

```
input BoxDraft {
  boxSize: String!
  sendToCustomer: Boolean!
  getFromCustomer: Boolean!
}
```

Notice how we can leave out the `_id` field, as I assume it is automatically generated by your server implementation. Then you can reference this type in your mutation.

```
type Mutation {
  addCustomer(
    firstName: String!, 
    lastName: String!, 
    email: String!, 
    password: String!, 
    address: String!, 
    city: String!, 
    state: String!, 
    zip: String!, 
    phone: String!
    boxes: [BoxDraft]
  ): Auth
  # ...
}
```

I would go even one step further and also define a draft type for `Customer`:

```
input CustomerDraft {
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  email: String!
  password: String! 
  address: String! 
  city: String! 
  state: String! 
  zip: String!
  phone: String!
  boxes: [BoxDraft]
}

type Mutation {
  addCustomer(draft: CustomerDraft!): Auth
}
```

Comment: Outstanding!  Thank you very much.

Comment: You can accept this answer as the correct answer and upvote so that I get some fake internet points as a reward 

Comment: I've accepted your answer as correct.  Looks like I don't have the ability to upvote yet.  Thanks again for helping a newbie out, Herku!